# How do i foreach mysql result as array session

Tags: mysql, foreach

I have a page were ["cart_array"] mange session to fetch total price and total quantity in the cart my problem is that am trying to foreach mysql result into ["cart_array"] as session so i can get total price and total quantity form mysql fetch result i tried:

```
<?php 
  $sqli = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `book`='$book'"); 
  $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sqli); // count the output amount
  if($productCount  0) { 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){ 
    foreach($row as $v);
   } 
   $id = $v["item_name"]; 
   $product_name = $v["book"]; 
   $price = $v["quantity"]; 
   $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $id, "quantity" => $price)); ?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: @Sumner Evans do you have any soluction or idea to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sqli = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `book`='$book'"); 
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sqli); // count the output amount

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){ 
    foreach($row as $v) {
      //$id = $v["item_name"]; //mybe id
      $_SESSION["cart_array"][] =  array(
         "item_id" =>  $v["id"], 
         "quantity" => $v["quantity"], 
         "product_name" => $v["book"]
        );
    }
}
```

I don't now, but in your code was some loop was empty (`foreach($row as $v);`) and in  `$_SESSION["cart_array"]` will be array now;

Comment: What about price variable as not included in your code

Comment: Thanks @konstantin for your impact but this do not work for me i think i can achieve this if i can get each each_item and price from mysql result into the session ["cart_array"] i try with
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){
$id = ["item_name"];
$product_name = $v["book"];
$price = ["quantity"];
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" =>  $id, "quantity" => $price)); and it work but i get only the last result instead of all the result in the query